# Android: Get Parent View of EditText in TextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to get the parent view of an EditText within the TextChangedListener?
I want to get the tag of its parent view whenever the text changes.

As Button.OnClick() has the View directly as a parameter and we can use getParent(), how to do something similar with EditText?

Edit: I need to avoid making global references. It would be good to know if there is any other event or method to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Method 1: Create an Instance Variable**

If you setup an instance variable to reference the view you will be able to access it throughout your entire class.

First define the `EditText` variable as an instance variable in your class

```
private EditText mEditText;
```

Then in some place such as `onCreate` or `onViewCreated` you can initialize your `EditText` and add the listener.

```
mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // Get the parent view of the edit text here 
        View parentView = mEditText.getParent();
    } 

});
```

Now you will be able to use the `mEditText` variable wherever you would like as shown above.

### **Method 2: Solve Without Instance Variable**

If you do not want to create an instance variable like `mEditText` in your fragment or activity you can create your own abstract class that implements `TextWatcher` as an alternate solution.

```
public abstract class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    private EditText editText;

    public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    public EditText getEditTextView() {
        return editText;
    }

    public ViewParent getParentView() {
        return editText.getParent();
    }

    public View getRootView() {
        return editText.getRootView();
    }
}
```

This will allow you to provide the `EditText` to the `TextWatcher` so it will be accessible within that scope.

```
    mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

    // Create a new instance of the MyTextWatcher class and pass it your EditText 
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(mEditText) {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // Get the view parent here
            ViewParent viewParent = getParentView();
        }
    });
```

Any methods that you add to your `MyTextWatcher` class will now be accessible from each of the callback methods you implement in your fragment or activity.

Comment: I had that idea but I need to avoid making global references. Edited the question. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include an alternate solution that does not use an instance variable.

Comment: Should the parameter in new instance of MyTextWatcher be mEditText and not editText?

Comment: Also, is there a way to access the current EditText view and not its parent?

Comment: It should have been mEditText, I've edited my answer. You can get the current EditText simply by calling getEditTextView(). I defined that method in the MyTextWatcher class as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I used OnFocusChangeListener on the EditText for now. It provides the View as the parameter just like OnClick.

```
new OnFocusChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

The only drawback is that the event triggers on changing focus, and not on every keystroke in the EditText.